# Что такое холодное чтение RAM?

Tags: безопасность, железо, ram

Что такое холодное чтение из оперативной памяти (RAM)?

Comment: Есть подвижки? Что-нибудь выяснили? Почти наверняка подразумевается что-то связанное с кешем. От себя могу предложить следующую [статью](http://www.1024cores.net/home/in-russian/ram---ne-ram-ili-cache-conscious-data-structures), раздел Hot/Cold Data Splitting. Оно?

Answer (score 1):

После отключения питания DRAM и SRAM сохраняют свое содержимое в течении некоторого времени (от нескольких секунд до нескольких минут). Это может использоваться для так называемой [*атаки методом холодной перезагрузки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack) (англ. [*cold boot attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)).

В течении того времени, пока память (будучи отключенной от питания) сохраняет свое содержимое, можно успеть это содержимое прочитать и записать на постоянный носитель.

Мы можем увеличить время, в течении которого память будет хранить свое содержимое, если физически *охладим* ее. Например, при температуре −50 °C процент ошибок при чтении близок к нулю и равен 0,000095.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Как говорится в [исследовании](http://s3.amazonaws.com/citpsite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/23195456/halderman.pdf), проведенном университетом Принстона..</sup>